# DeleteView is missing a queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-class-based-views

So i'm working on an inventory app, a django-app where you can handle inventory in a company. I've been using mostly class-based so far in my `views.py`, and i can already create and edit all of my models using class-based views.

So when it comes to the `generic.DeleteView`, i have some problems.

**This is my function in** `views.py`:

```
class DeleteItemView(DeleteView):
    model: Item
    success_url: reverse_lazy('inventory_app:items')
    template_name = 'inventory/detail_pages/item_detail.html'
```

**And this is my URL to the function:**

```
path('items/<int:pk>/delete/', views.DeleteItemView.as_view(), name='delete_item')
```

When i call this url with a button, **this error appears:**

```
DeleteItemView is missing a QuerySet. Define DeleteItemView.model, DeleteItemView.queryset, or override DeleteItemView.get_queryset().
```

So i heard online that this appears when `/<int:pk>/` is missing in the url. But i have it in mine, so whats the problem here?

Thank you already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class DeleteItemView(DeleteView):
    model = Item
    success_url = reverse_lazy('inventory_app:items')
    template_name = 'inventory/detail_pages/item_detail.html'
```

remove the colon `(:)` and change to `=`

Comment: Thank you very much, i always forget this one XD